# Transform an excel formula containing a semicolon to a r formula

Tags: r, excel

I need to calculate the coordinates of some points based on the azimut and the distance to another point, which I have done on excel. My formula (on excel) contains a semicolon (which I understand is used to separate parameters in a function) and I need to use this same formula on my datas on R ... which I don't know how.

On excel I have the following one :

```
=LC(-3) + ATAN2(COS(LC(-5)/6371)-SIN(LC(-4))* **SIN(LC(-1)); SIN(LC(-2))** *SIN(LC(-5)/6371)*COS(LC(-4)))
```

The beginning of my R script

```r
install.packages("REdaS")
library("REdaS")

Mydata <- read.csv("xxx.csv", header = T, sep=";", dec=",")
Mydata <- Mydata [, c("placette", "azimut", "dist", "essence", "lat_placette", "long_placette")]

# Coordinates in radians

rad_lat <- deg2rad(Mydata$lat_placette)
rad_lon <- deg2rad(Mydata$long_placette)
rad <- deg2rad(Mydata$azimut)

Mydata <- cbind(Mydata, rad_lat, rad_lon, rad)

# Calculaion of latitude

Latitude <- asin(sin(Mydata$rad_lat)*cos((Mydata$dist)/6371)+cos(Mydata$rad_lat)*sin(Mydata$dist/6371)*cos(Mydata$rad))

rad2deg(Latitude)

Mydata <- cbind(Mydata,Latitude)

# Calculation of longitude

Longitude <- Mydata$rad_lon + arctan(cos(Mydata$dist/6371) - sin(Mydata$rad_lat) * sin(Mydata$Latitude)) ; sin(Mydata$rad) * sin(Mydata$dist/6371) * cos(Mydata$rad_lat))

rad2deg(Longitude)
```

I need to replace the ";" to get my result and I'm totally lost :-( !

I hope I've been clear, I'm not a native speaker, and I'm not a very skilled R coder either ...

Anyway, thanks for your help !

Comment: R uses commas to separate arguments (parameters in Excel) in a function.

Comment: What is `LC()`? If a user function, please show its definition. Also, is the double asterisk your attempt to bold the code line or actually used in formula?

Comment: LC() is the way excel refers to other cells from the same line (LC (-3) is the third cell left from the one where the formula is).

Comment: The atan function only accepts one argument unfortunately. I really don't understand how it can work on excel ...

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, I wrote =ATAN2(1.5;2) which gives 0.927295218001612. In R, you a have atan(2 / 1.5) = 0.927295218001612

Maybe you can use something like this in R :

```
term1 <- sin(Mydata$rad) * sin(Mydata$dist/6371) * cos(Mydata$rad_lat)
term2 <- cos(Mydata$dist/6371) - sin(Mydata$rad_lat) * sin(Mydata$Latitude))
atan(term1 / term2)
```